# How to add a FontAwesomeIcon to a Java File

Tags: java, javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder, fontawesomefx

Hey I want to add a FontAwesomeIcon to a plain Java File - using fontawesomefx.

I generated it with the SceneBuilder and I want to use the graphic that includes FontAwesomeIcon to my Button.

This is the code that SceneBuilder generated:

```
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #c93636; -fx-background-radius: 45px; -fx-text-fill: #fff;" text="Zurücksetzen" textAlignment="CENTER">
   <font>
      <Font size="36.0" />
   </font>
   <HBox.margin>
      <Insets left="50.0" />
   </HBox.margin>
   <graphic>
      <FontAwesomeIcon fill="WHITE" glyphName="UNDO" />
   </graphic></Button>
```

I have everything setup in the Java file - the button works and look like it should the only problem is that I don't know how to load the FontAwesomeFXIcon in the Java file.

This is the part where the Button gets created:

```
    btnNext.setPrefSize(RESOLUTION.getWidth() / 2, RESOLUTION.getHeight() / 10);                
    btnNext.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #30b832; -fx-background-radius: 90px; -fx-text-fill: #fff; -fx-font-size: 4em;");
    btnNext.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

It looks like this: [image]

But I want it to look like this: [image]

Now I tried some things but it did not work.. I guess I have to set the graphic field like its created in the FXML file and then assign a FontAwesomeIcon but I really don't understand how to do this.

I've seen some similar questions but they only want to know on how to use it in FXML which I already do.

I need to have this in the .java file. Without accessing the FXML File and the Controller because I will not use it like this.

Comment: load the font like so, `  Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"), 20);
` obviously changing to suit... then use the FontAwesome unicode and set it to the textProperty, for example `btnNext.setText("\uF067");` Or just use a FontAwesome library for JavaFX

Comment: Thanks for the reply I actually got it in another way somehow.. I will post it in an answer.

Comment: Please do so it can help others

Comment: yeah I did - thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually found a Solution myself and it is pretty straight forward.

First I create a new FontAwesomeIcon Object:

```
FontAwesomeIcon fntIcon = new FontAwesomeIcon();
```

then I assign the GylphName like this:

```
fntIcon.setGlyphName("UNDO");
```

after that I can assign it to my Button and it works! :

```
btnReset.setGraphic(fntIcon);
```

Honestly that was very simple and straight forward !

~Faded